# actionbarsherlock actionbar tab reversed

Tags: android, android-actionbar, icons, actionbarsherlock, android-tabs

While i use actionbarshelock in android 2.2 with home icon disable and tab mode enabled as below:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

It ended up with the tabs being above of the actionbar. What's expected is that the tabs should be located below the actionbar.

The ABS offical demo app also has the same problem in the 'feature toggle' page.

I'm not sure if this's a bug of ABS or misusing the API.
Anyone saw this before or have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it is a issue and there are a few solutions.
I tried some of them and succeeded - take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/327).

Comment: thanks, seems it's the default behavior of native actionbar, although it's very weird. i walked around this by using customer view.